# XML Display Formatting

Tags: php, html, xml

I have a function that generates XML from a source. It works perfectly however, when certain fields are long. It stretches the table to the right and ruins the formatting of the website. Is there a way to maybe insert line breaks after a certain amount of text or keep it within the table space?

The function for the code is:

```
function generateXML($mlsID, $xmlLocation) {

if (file_exists($xmlLocation)) {
    $simpleXMLobject = simplexml_load_file($xmlLocation);
    if (!$simpleXMLobject) {
        echo 'ERROR: unable to parse XML file';
        exit;
    }

    $mlsIdWasLocatedInXMLfile = false;
    foreach ($simpleXMLobject->Listing as $listing) {
        if ($listing->ListingDetails->MlsId == $mlsID) {
            $mlsIdWasLocatedInXMLfile = true;
            //echo '<table width ="500" style="table-layout:fixed" >';
            $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
            $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
            $dom->formatOutput = true;
            $dom->loadXML($listing->asXML());
            echo("<pre>" . htmlspecialchars($dom->saveXML()) . "</pre>");
            //echo '</table>';
        }
    }
    if ($mlsIdWasLocatedInXMLfile === false) {
        echo "MLS ID NOT FOUND IN XML FILE";
    }
} else {
    echo 'ERROR: file not found';
}
}
```

Comment: Some css with max-width and overflow: scroll, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should not format the output, as it would make no sense sometimes. Better change your website - make element, in which you show your information scrollable.

If you need to do word wrapping, try using this function: wordwrap

Comment: How I can I incorporate wordwrap to the xml? Can you give an example?

Comment: Well replacing your output to echo("<pre>" . htmlspecialchars(wordwrap($dom->saveXML(), 500, "<br />")) . "</pre>"); should do the job

Comment: I tried that code, but it still extends all the way across the screen. I even did an extreme number like 50 instead of 500.

Comment: Oh, my bad. You are doing htmlspecialchars, which removes <br> tags. Switch htmlspecialchars and wordwrap function order, it should work then

Comment: Oh wow! lol. I realize that too now. Thanks that worked perfectly.